# How does Spotify or Deezer download and store music for offline use on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storage, core-storage

Which component or method do they use to store it? Is there any easier way to store music offline?
How can I store those sounds locally so I can use it for offline use?
How can I take a song from youtube and store it on phone locally so it can be used for offline use? I just need a method or steps to do it not the whole code...Thank you cheers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I voted to close this question as off-topic because all code-related questions should be asked on Stack Overflow.  I would recommend you simplify your question to focus on 1-2 points otherwise the users there might vote to close your question as being too broad.

Comment: Spotify saves the music files to your devices app cache which does take up storage. These music files are in Ogg Vorbis format but are also encrypted by Spotify so no other media scanner will recognize them as music files (such and a internal or external file explorer). You can't store them locally since they are encrypted and DRM-protected.

https://support.spotify.com/us/using_spotify/system_settings/storage-and-data-information/

Answer (score 1):

Afaik in terms of storage, apps only have access to their sandboxed container. Spotify stores offline music in in an encrypted format that isn't usable by other programs.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I take a song from youtube and store it on phone locally so it
>   can be used for offline use?

1. [Downloading YouTube music videos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321650/downloading-youtube-music-videos/321668#321668)
2. [Transfer mp3 files from Mac to iPhone Music app using iTunes 12.0.1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161840/transfer-mp3-files-from-mac-to-iphone-music-app-using-itunes-12-0-1)

Comment: not this way, on the users device using code?